# pfSense view allowed/permitted log

Tags: pfsense

I've just installed pfSense and noticed that it only log "blocked" traffic.

[image]

*Image taken from https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/monitoring/logs/firewall.html

How do I enable "allowed/permitted" traffic as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual page you refer to links directly to the log settings manual: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/monitoring/logs/settings.html#monitor-log-settings

> In the GUI, the Settings tab under Status > System Logs controls how the logging system behaves.

> **`Log Packets from Default Pass Rules`**

> Unchecked by default. When set, logging will occur for packets matching the default pass out rules on interfaces. Setting this option will generate a large amount of log data for connections outbound from the firewall. The best practice is to only enable this for brief periods of time while performing troubleshooting or diagnostics.

Comment: Found it, little bit different though. `Log packets matched from the default pass rules put in the ruleset`